# How to evaluate $\int_0^1\ln(1-x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to compute $\int_0^1\ln(1-x)dx$.

Using integration by parts we have: $\int_0^1\ln(1-x)dx=\int_0^1(x)'\ln(1-x)dx=x\ln(1-x)|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{x}{1-x}dx$ but limit at $1$ of $x\ln(1-x)$ is $-\infty$ and $\int_0^1\frac{x}{1-x}dx$ does not converge.

I know the answer is $-1$ because desired integral is equal to $\int_0^1\ln(x)dx$ or using integration by parts but with $-(1-x)$ not $x$ yields $-1$ but why first approach does not work and produce false equality?

Answer (score 7):

You have to do the substitution $y=1-x$. The problem is that in your solution you will have two limits that diverge but cancel each other out. You involuntarily split the limits, which makes it a bit confusing since you get something of the form $\infty-\infty$. This doesn't mean that your integral doesn't exist (it's an indeterminate form).

Comment: Yeah but it is weird to me that from convergent integral I get $\infty -\infty$

Comment: It's an indetermined form, you involuntarily split a limit and that causes that. A simple example of this is $a = \lim_{x\to\infty}(x-a)-x$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-a) - \lim_{x\to\infty}x = \infty-\infty$. Not much to do about it, except for being carefull with your limits.

Comment: But I can't split the limits in your example because I would get $\infty-\infty$ but in example from question I got $\infty-\infty$ and you say it is not wrong

Comment: You can solve the other integral and than take the limit over both expressions. Formally you need to find the whole primitive function first and then apply the endpoints

Answer (score 2):

Integrating by parts works a little better if you make a substitution first:

$$\int_0^1 \ln(1-x) \, dx \stackrel{u=\ln(1-x)}= \int_{-\infty}^0 ue^u\,du \stackrel{\rm IBP}= -\int_{-\infty}^0 e^u\,du$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the Taylor series expansion of $\ln(1-x)$. We could use it because $0\le x<1$: $$\int_0^1\ln(1-x)dx=-\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}kdx$$Given that the integral converges, we could interchange the integral and summation symbols: $$-\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}kdx=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\int_0^1x^kdx=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(k+1)}$$Using partial fraction decomposition: $$-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(k+1)}=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)=-\left(\left(1-\frac12\right)+\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)+\left(\frac13-\frac14\right)+...\right)$$This telescopes, so the answer is $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

First, substitute $u = 1 - x$, which makes $du = -1dx$, and thus $dx = -1du$. Now, the integral becomes $-\ln(u)$, which is equal to $-u \ln(u) + u$. Undo the substitution to get $(-1 + x) \ln(1 - x) + 1 - x$.
Finally, plug in $1$ and $0$ into this expression to find that the answer is undefined because $\ln(1 - x)$ is undefined at $1$. However, if you think of $(-1 + 1) \ln(1 - 1) + 1 - 1$ as $0$ because $-1 + 1$, which is being multiplied by the $\ln$, is $0$, then the answer is $-1$ because $(-1 + 1) \ln(1 - 1) + 1 - 1 - (-\ln(1) + 1) = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

$((1-x)\ln(1-x))'
=-\ln(1-x)-1
$
so
$\int \ln(1-x)dx
=(1-x)\ln(1-x)-x+c
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^1 \ln(1-x)dx
&=((1-x)\ln(1-x)-x+c)|_0^1\\
&=(\lim_{x \to 1}(1-x)\ln(1-x))-1-0\\
&=-1\\
\text{since}\\
\lim_{y \to 0} y \ln(y)
&=\lim_{z \to \infty} \frac1{z} \ln(\frac1{z})
\qquad y=\frac1{z}\\
&=\lim_{z \to \infty} - \dfrac{\ln(z)}{z}\\
&=0\\
\text{or}\\
\lim_{y \to 0} y \ln(y)
&=\lim_{z \to \infty} e^{-z}\ln(e^{-z})
\qquad y=e^{-z}\\
&=\lim_{z \to \infty} -z e^{-z}\\
&=0\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Because this is an **improper** integral, if you want to do integration by parts as in the OP, you have to do it like this:
$$
\int_0^t \ln(1-x)\;dx = x\ln(1-x)\Big|_0^t + \int_0^t\frac{x}{1-x}\;dx
\\ \qquad=t\log(1-t)-t-\ln(1-t) = -t - (1-t)\ln(1-t)
$$
and
$$
\int_0^1 \ln(1-x)\;dx = \lim_{t\to 1^-}\int_0^t \ln(1-x)\;dx =
\lim_{t\to 1^-}\big[-t - (1-t)\ln(1-t)\big] = -1 .
$$